# Need to kill a Java program started by Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Tags: java, command-line, runtime.exec, freeze

In a Java program I am running another Java program using the following command:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo.bat | java -Xms64M -Xmx1G -cp "+execFilePath+" "+inputFileName+" "+inputParam);
```

The invocation is working fine, but if due to bad coding the executed Java file (`inputFileName`) is hanging, say, due to some infinite loop, a new process which got started, is not ending. Now, I need to kill that process in my code.

I am able to detect if the Java program is hanging by using TimeOut. But, I don't know how to get the process id of this executed Java program and kill it once TimeOut happens.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should really look into using a `ProcessBuilder`.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you can call `destroy` on your Process instance. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy%28%29)

I notice however that you are starting one process and pipe its output to another. The simple approach will most probabely only kill the former (your `echo.bat` process).

Therefore, you need a more complex scenario. Do the following:

1. Start a process calling `echo.bat` only
2. Wait until it is finished
3. Read all of its output through its output stream (`Process.getOutputStream()`)
4. Start another process, calling the java program only.
5. Write the read data to its input (write to `Process.getInputStream()`)
6. This second process instance will be your java process

As *fge* mentioned above, take a look at [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), as it simplyfies some of the steps. Especially setting up the input stream can be accomplished before actually starting the program

Comment: destroy() method kills the Runtime.getRuntime().exec() process itself and not the Java program started by it.